# misconception about prototypal inheritance JS

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, ecmascript-5

could you please help me to solve this misconception about prototypal inheritance in JavaScript

```js
function Animal(name) {
    this.name = name;
}


Animal.prototype.speak = function() {
    console.log("My name is " + this.name);
};

Animal.sayMoo = function(){
console.log("Mooooo!");
};

var animal = new Animal('Monty');

animal.speak(); // My name is Monty
animal.sayMoo; // undefined
```

as far as  I know any instance of an object has all it properties, and in this example animal (instance of Animal) only has what inside the constructor "this.name" and the method "speek()" **but not** "sayMoo" because I did not use ( Animal.protoype.sayMoo = ...

I think maybe animal or any instance only inherit what is inside the Animal.prototype

is that the right answer? **if yes**, why animal inherits what inside the constructor ? maybe all properties inside the constructor go automatically to the prototype, so it can be inherited by any instance?

I wish i Solve this

Comment: An instance of `Animal` *inherits* the `prototype`, and in addition you're very explicitly setting `this.name`, where `this` is your new instance. So no, it doesn't "go to the prototype"; it very explicitly is a property of the object, because that's what you're setting.

Comment: ohhh! it does make sense now. thank a lot. Just to make sure so any property outside the prototype can not be inherited by any instance, right ?

Comment: ohhh! it does make sense now. thank a lot. Just to make sure so any property outside the prototype can not be inherited by any instance, right ?

Comment: Right, any property directly attached to an object is directly attached to that object and won't usually be inherited by anything.

Comment: (I'm saying "usually" because Javascript is very malleable, and the `prototype` is in fact also "just an object"… so things *can* be inherited in all sorts of ways if you pass them around…)